# Empty list of hits while iterating over pages of an Elastic Search query

Tags: python, elasticsearch, pagination

I am using the following code to iterate over multiple pages when getting the results of an ElasticSearch query.

```
class MyClass: 

    ....

    def _search_after_from_response(
            self,
            es_index: str,
            body: dict,  # the ES query
            response: dict,  # the response of the first query
    ) -> List[dict]:

        res_list = []

        # First query
        response = self.es.search(index=es_index, body=body, request_timeout=self.request_timeout)
        results = self._get_results_from_response(response)
        res_list += results
        
        # Iterate over the pages using search_after 
        bookmark = [response['hits']['hits'][-1]['sort'][0], str(response['hits']['hits'][-1]['sort'][1])]

        body_loop = copy.deepcopy(body)
        body_loop['search_after'] = bookmark

        while len(response['hits']['hits']) < size:
            # Run the query on ES
            res = self.es.search(index=es_index, body=body_loop, request_timeout=self.request_timeout)
            # Process results
            for el in res['hits']['hits']:
                response['hits']['hits'].append(el)
            results = self._get_results_from_response(res)
            res_list += results
            # Prepare next search
            bookmark = [res['hits']['hits'][-1]['sort'][0], str(response['hits']['hits'][-1]['sort'][1])]   # <----- ERROR
            body_loop['search_after'] = bookmark
        return res_list

    def _get_results_from_response(self, response: dict) -> List[dict]:
        return [
            hit['_source'] for hit in response['hits']['hits']
        ]
```

Sometimes I get an error when creating a bookmark in the loop because `res['hits']['hits']` is an empty list. How is this possible?

Note: I am not providing the full query because I suspect the issue is more generic and not related to my specific query, but I may be wrong. Let me know if you need more information, thanks!